# Understanding (simple?) C++ Partial Template Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

**Note:** this seems to be a repost of a problem: [C++ - Overload templated class method with a partial specilization of that method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206080/c-overload-templated-class-method-with-a-partial-specilization-of-that-method/5206117#5206117)

I have boiled down a problem I am having with C++ template specialization down to a simple case.

It consists of a simple 2-parameter template class `Thing`, where I would like to specialize `Thing<A,B>::doSomething()` for `B=int`.

```
#include <cstdio>

// A 3-parameter template class.
template <class A, class B>
class Thing
{
public:
    Thing(A a, B b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
    B doSomething();
private:
    A a_;
    B b_;
};

// The generic case works as expected.
template <class A, class B>
B Thing<A,B>::doSomething()
{
    return b_;
}

// This specialization does not work!
template <class A>
int Thing<A,int>::doSomething()
{
    return b_+1;
}

int main() {
    // Setup our thing.
    Thing<double,int> thing(1.0,2);
    // This doesn't compile - but works with the generic case.
    printf("Expecting 3, and getting %i\n", thing.doSomething());
    // Clean up.
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, `g++` exits with the error:

```
partial_specialization.cpp:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Thing<A, int>’
partial_specialization.cpp:8: error: declaration of ‘class Thing<A, int>’
```

The `clang++` compiler is a bit more verbose, but has the same problem:

```
partial_specialization.cpp:30:19: error: nested name specifier 'Thing<A, int>::' for declaration does not
      refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
int Thing<A,int>::doSomething()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
partial_specialization.cpp:32:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'b_'
    return b_+1;
           ^
2 errors generated.
```

I have read and understood that partial template specializations on functions aren't allowed - but I thought I was partially specializing over classes of `Thing` in this case.

Any ideas?

**What I did:** A workaround, as determined from the link provided by the accepted answer:

```
template< class T >
inline T foo( T const & v ) { return v; }

template<>
inline int foo( int const & v ) { return v+1; }

// The generic case works as expected.
template <class A, class B>
B Thing<A,B>::doSomething()
{
    return foo(b_);
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Partial specialization of a function template, whether it is member function template or stand-alone function template, is not allowed by the Standard:

```
template<typename T, typename U> void f() {} //okay  - primary template
template<typename T> void f<T,int>() {}      //error - partial specialization
template<> void f<unsigned char,int>() {}    //okay  - full specialization
```

But you can partially specialize the class template itself.  You can do something like this:

```
template <class A>
class Thing<A,int>  //partial specialization of the class template
{
    //..
    int doSomething();
};

template <class A>
int Thing<A,int>::doSomething()  { /* do whatever you want to do here */ }
```

Note that when you partially specialize a class template, then the template parameter-list of member function (in its definition outside the class), **must match** the template parameter list of the class template partial specialization. That means, for the above partial specialization of the class template, you cannot define this:

```
template <class A>
int Thing<A,double>::doSomething(); //error
```

Its not allowed, because the template parameter-list in function definition didn't match the template parameter-list of the class template partial specialization. §14.5.4.3/1 from the Standard (2003) says,

> The template parameter list of a member of a class template partial specialization **shall match** the template parameter list of the class template partial specialization.[...]

For more on this, read my answer here:

[C++ - Overload templated class method with a partial specilization of that method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206080/c-overload-templated-class-method-with-a-partial-specilization-of-that-method/5206117#5206117)

---

So what is the solution? Would you partially specialize your class along with all the repetitive work?

A simple solution would be work delegation, instead of partially specializing the class template. Write a *stand-alone* function template and specialize this as:

```
template <class B>
B doTheActualSomething(B & b) { return b;  }

template <>
int doTheActualSomething<int>(int & b) { return b + 1; }
```

And then call this function template from `doSomething()` member function as:

```
template <class A, class B>
B Thing<A,B>::doSomething() { return doTheActualSomething<B>(b_); }
```

---

Since in your particular case, `doTheActualSomething` needs to know the value of *only one* member, namely `b_`, the above solution is fine, as you can pass the value to the function as argument whose type is the template *type* argument `B`, and specialization for `int` is possible being it full-specialization.

But imagine if it needs to access multiple members, *type* of each depends on the template *type* argument-list, then defining a stand-alone function template wouldn't solve the problem, because now there will be more than one *type* argument to the function template, and you cannot *partially* specialize the function for just, say, one *type* (as its not allowed).

So in this case you can define a class template instead, which defines a static non-template member function `doTheActualSomething`. Here is how:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct Worker
{
   B doTheActualSomething(Thing<A,B> *thing)
   {
      return thing->b_;
   }
};

//partial specialization of the class template itself, for B = int
template<typename A>
struct Worker<A,int>
{
   int doTheActualSomething(Thing<A,int> *thing)
   {
      return thing->b_ + 1;
   }
};
```

Notice that you can use `thing` pointer to access any member of the class. Of course, if it needs to access private members, then you've to make `struct Worker` a  friend of `Thing` class template, as:

```
//forward class template declaration
template<typename T, typename U> struct Worker

template <class A, class B>
class Thing
{
    template<typename T, typename U>  friend struct Worker; //make it friend
   //...
};
```

Now delegate the work to the friend as:

```
template <class A, class B>
B Thing<A,B>::doSomething()
{
    return Worker<A,B>::doTheActualSomething(this); //delegate work
}
```

Two points to be noted here:

- In this solution, `doTheActualSomething` is not a member function *template*. Its not enclosing class which is template. Hence we can *partially* specialize the class template anytime, to get the desired effect of the *partial* member function template specialization.
- Since we pass `this` pointer as argument to the function, we can access any member of the class `Thing<A,B>`, even private members, as `Worker<T,U>` is also a friend.

Complete online demo : http://www.ideone.com/uEQ4S

---

Now there is still a chance of improvement. Now all instantiations of `Worker` class template are friends of all instantiation of `Thing` class template. So we can restrict this many-to-many friendship as:

```
template <class A, class B>
class Thing
{
    friend struct Worker<A,B>; //make it friend
   //...
};
```

Now only one instantiation of `Worker` class template is a friend of one instantiation of `Thing` class template. That is one-to-one friendship. That is, `Worker<A,B>` is a friend of `Thing<A,B>`. `Worker<A,B>` is NOT a friend of `Thing<A,C>`.

This change requires us to write the code in somewhat different order. See the complete demo, with all the ordering of class and function definitions and all:

http://www.ideone.com/6a1Ih

Comment: Good link. I read in your quotation "A class template specialization is a distinct template.". Does this mean that my class specialization will have to define all the expected member data of the original `Thing<A,B>`? As I read it, the answer is yes...

Comment: An interesting bypass of the problem of having to redefine everything is also listed in the link you sent... see my use of `foo` above, as adapted from Alf P. Steinbach's answer.

Comment: The answer is wrong: *Specialization of member function without specializing the class template, is not allowed* is **false**. You cannot *partially* specialize a member function in any context but you can specialize a member function of a class template. `template <typename T> struct test { void foo() {} }; template <> void test<int>::foo() { std::cout << "specialized"; }` is perfectly valid.

Comment: The workaround is also incorrect: you **cannot** partially specialize a function template.

Comment: @David: You're correct regarding the partial specialization. I meant the same, but somehow I carelessly wrote my post and didn't re-read it till you pointed out. And in fact my answer in the other link is correct, and it *emphasizes* what you said.

Comment: It is still incorrect: you *cannot* partially specialize a member function. You can implement a generic (non-specialized) member function of a partial specialization, but you cannot partially specialize a member (or non-member) function *ever*.

Comment: @David: I didn't partially specialize a member function

Comment: @David: Ohh.. I understand now what you meant. If I partially specialize a template as `X<T,int>`, then I can implement `X<T,in>::f()` which is generic for this partial specialization of the class template, but I cannot implement `X<T,double>::f()`. That is true. But I didn't do that.

Comment: It is just that the first sentence is misleading: *Partial specialization of member function without partially specializing the class template, is not allowed.* **No** partial specialization of a member (or free) function is allowed *anywhere*. The sentence seems to indicate that once you have partially specialized the class, then you can *partially* specialize the function, it is just a nitpick, but I believe that in technical descriptions it is important to be precise.

Comment: @David: I think, I should delete this post, and add another one (following your pattern of course), explaining the misleading sentences. But then I cannot delete an "accepted" answer. :|

Comment: @David: Yeah, to be precise is important. But I didn't know one can go to this extent. haha...

Comment: @Dan: Yes. I will edit it after some time (30 mins or so), with another solution I've in my mind.

Comment: @David: Please see my post. Do let me know if there is any chance of improvement. Your comments are valueable for me. Maybe, I can still improve it.

Comment: @Dan: See the post. I edited it extensively (as now I'm at home, not in office :D).

Comment: Mostly right, the friendship could (probably should) be more explicit (i.e. you don't want to befriend all instantiations of the template `Worker` but rather only `Worker<A,B>`... but not a big deal.

Comment: @David: Yes. I've added that part also. See the last paragraph.

Answer (score 11):

This is a very often found problem, and there is a surprisingly *simple* solution. I will show it in an artificial example, because it's more clearer than to use your code, and you will have to understand it to adapt it to your code

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct TwoTypes { };

template<typename A, typename B>
struct X {
  /* forwards ... */
  void f() { fImpl(TwoTypes<A, B>()); }

  /* special overload for <A, int> */
  template<typename A1>
  void fImpl(TwoTypes<A1, int>) {
    /* ... */
  }

  /* generic */
  template<typename A1, typename B1>
  void fImpl(TwoTypes<A1, B1>) {
    /* ... */
  }
};
```

Explicitly specializing functions is never (almost never?) the right way. In my work as a programmer, I've never explicitly specialized a function template. Overloading and partial ordering is superior.

Comment: The last sentence is so very true, I wish more programmer would knew its value. I remember an article on GotW, that extensively explains the problem with specialized function templates, I can't look for it right now though.

Comment: Also, the overloads could be free functions and you could just pass `this` instead of a new type if you don't need direct access on to the class internals. On a side note, with C++0x one can make a generic `template<class... Types> struct OrderingKey{};` instead of a number of additional structs for each number of types.