# Invalid use of incomplete type in conversion operator with forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a class defined in a header file like this(although this is a stripped down version):

**my_class.hpp**

```
// header guard

template<typename T, std::size_t First, std::size_t Second, class Enable = void>
class other_class;

template<typename T, std::size_t Size, class Enable = void>
class my_class;                        // I have my reasons

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class my_class<T, Size, typename std::enable_if<condition1>::type>{
    public:
        template<
                std::size_t S = Size,
                typename = typename std::enable_if<other_condition1>::type
        >
        operator other_class<T, 1, Size>();
};

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class my_class<T, Size, typename std::enable_if<condition2>::type>{
    public:
        template<
                std::size_t S = Size,
                typename = typename std::enable_if<other_condition2>::type
        >
        operator other_class<T, 1, Size>();
};
```

then another class in a header file like this:

**other_class.hpp**

```
#include "my_class.hpp"

template<typename T, std::size_t First, std::size_t Second>
class other_class<T, First, Second, typename std::enable_if<condition>::type>{
    public:
        other_class(...){
            // ...
        }

        my_class<T, First> data[Second];
};

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
template<std::size_t S, typename>
my_class<T, Size>::operator other_class<T, 1, Size>(){
    return other_class<T, 1, Size>(...);
}
```

and all was well until I wanted to define that conversion operator :/ Now I am getting an error about incomplete type `class my_class<T, Size>` in the implementation of the operator.

This seems very strange to me as I have been using `my_class` as the data for `other_class` just fine and that would require it to be complete (it calls the default constructor of the class).

What exactly is causing the error here?

System is Ubuntu 14.04 with GCC 4.8.2

Comment: Does `my_class.hpp` include `other_class.hpp`?

Comment: No, or I wouldn't forward declare it

Comment: I'm asking because when I fixup your code to replace the dummy identifiers like `condition` and ellipses, the only error I get is that you're using `other_class` without template parameters on you `return other_class(...)`, unless I include `my_class.h` first, in which case it rains errors.

Comment: Can you post something that I can actually compile to show the problem?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode are your implementations in header files or .cpp files? (Putting template implementations in .cpp files is a common mistake and will cause the problem you are experiencing).

Comment: I think adding the info that I declare 2 specializations will help. All of the implementations are in header files, this isn't my first time doing template programming :P

Comment: like kec mentioned; the code you posted is not compiling due to missing variables (condition, etc). My blind guess would be that you're missing some `typename` for the type, as it is incomplete. But without compiling code, there is nothing to verify

Answer (score 2):

You need to repeat `std::enable_if<condition>` as the third parameter of `my class` in the definition of the conversion operator:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
template<std::size_t S, typename>
my_class<T, Size,    typename std::enable_if<condition>::type>::
                  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
operator other_class<T, 1, Size>(){
    // return ...
}
```

So this definition is instantiated whenever `my_class` specialization is, under the same `condition`. Otherwise, you get into the primary template of `my_class` which is undefined (hence incomplete).

Using dummy conditions, this [compiles in gcc/clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fee61ac26d61d145).

**EDIT**

Checking [Understanding (simple?) C++ Partial Template Specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6138439/2644390), I now realize that when the template parameter list in `my_class` specialization and conversion operator definition do not match exactly, the compiler interprets the latter as a *member function specialization* for a class that is not specialized itself. This is not allowed.

I understand this must be the case because I get exactly the same compiler errors:

- gcc: `invalid use of incomplete type my_class<T, Size>`, and
- clang: `nested name specifier 'my_class<T, Size>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization`.

(of course, neither message is really helpful).

Here is a [reduced example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faa9022491d6c3bb) reproducing the error:

```
template<typename T>
using enable = typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T)>=0>::type;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct A;

template<typename T>
struct A<T, enable<T>>{ void f(); };

template<typename T>
void A<T, enable<T>>::  // compiles
// void A<T>::  // does not compile
f() { }
```

**EDIT 2**

I think the following applies from iso 14.5.5.3/1:

**14.5.5.3 Members of class template specializations**

> 1. The template parameter list of a member of a class template partial specialization shall match the template parameter list of the class template partial specialization. The template argument list of a member of a class template partial specialization shall match the template argument list of the class template partial specialization.

Comment: I've tried this, the compiler complains about the prototype not matching any in the class; although my conditions are hefty and make the compiler errors look absolutely disgusting :L

Comment: Don't know how much it helps, but I've reduced the code to [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/513deb8b4d0cb140).

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Check edit and linked question. As for conditions, you may simplify by using alias templates as in my reduced example.

Comment: If it's not too much you could have a look at the actual files here:
[Vector](https://github.com/RamblingMadMan/InfinityTK/blob/master/itk/InfinityTK/math/vector.hpp) and [Matrix](https://github.com/RamblingMadMan/InfinityTK/blob/master/itk/InfinityTK/math/matrix.hpp)

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Where exactly? (check also edit 2 with a quote from the standard).

Comment: Vector line 73/74 and matrix right at the bottom is where it is implemented

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any declaration and definition that really match. Vector l73/74 says `operator vec_base`; matrix bottom says `operator mat_base`.

Comment: That says `operator mat_base`: [THAT](https://github.com/RamblingMadMan/InfinityTK/blob/master/itk/InfinityTK/math/vector.hpp#L74) and that says the same: [THAT](https://github.com/RamblingMadMan/InfinityTK/blob/master/itk/InfinityTK/math/matrix.hpp#L190)

Comment: `vec_base == my_class` and `mat_base == other_class`

Comment: Ok, now I see (files have changed in the meantime). So declaration and definition seem identical except for matrix/l188 `template<std::size_t S, typename>` where second parameter is missing. The complete one would be `typename std::enable_if<(S > 1)>::type` (from vector l73). Have tried this?

Comment: I think you mis-read it, the `S` and `typename` parameters aren't affecting the `mat_base`

Comment: They aren't, but they are affecting the definition of the `vec_base` member function (conversion operator). Anyhow, I can't see much more from here :-)