# Tracking memory consumption of a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization

I have a class for which I'd like an estimation of how much memory it's consuming:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class MyTemplateClass
{
    size_t EstimateMemoryConsumption() const
    {
        // the memory consumption is a function of the size of the first template argument
        return f(sizeof(T));
    }
}
```

And this works fine. Recently I've been asked to support `T == std::string`.
The current implementation doesn't work because `sizeof(std::string)` doesn't reflect the memory consumption of an `std::string` (I need to call `capacity()` on the `std::string`). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138439/understanding-simple-c-partial-template-specialization), I cannot give a partial specialization for the member function (for `T == std::string`, and any `U`)

Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Refactor a base class with one template parameter, and then derive from this class.

Comment: you cannot do it generically, what about `std::vector<std::string>`? for every solution you'll find, you can always wrap it in another container class, breaking your solution.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether there is a single T data member, or a container of T, or anything else. Can you add more details on what f is and in where the type T is used in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make memory consumption a function of the template parameter itself.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class MyTemplateClass
{
    size_t EstimateMemoryConsumption() const
    {
        return estimate<T>(my_data_member);
    }
};
```

```
template <typename T>
size_t estimate(const T&) noexcept { return sizeof(T); }

template <>
size_t estimate<std::string>(const std::string& x) noexcept 
{ 
    return x.capacity(); 
}
```

Comment: This answer is all good and well assuming there is just a single member of type T, but I'm not sure that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Use traits to achieve specialization:

```
template <typename T>
class MyTemplateClassTraits
{
public:
    static size_t EstimateMemoryConsumption(T& member)
    {
        return 0; // implement...
    }
};

template <>
class MyTemplateClassTraits<std::string>
{
public:
    static size_t EstimateMemoryConsumption(std::string& member)
    {
        return 0;  // implement...
    }
};
```

Without changing your current API:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class MyTemplateClass
{
    //...

    size_t EstimateMemoryConsumption() const
    {
        // the memory consumption is a function of the size of the first template argument
        return MyTemplateClassTraits<T>::EstimateMemoryConsumption(t_data_member);
    }

    //...
}
```